# Unnecessary Peer Assisted Networking dialog box

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash, flashdevelop

We are close to deploying a build of our product. However, we are cursed by a Peer Assisted Networking permissions dialog, which we do not want.

We don't need to use anything that relies on peer assisted networking and believe the dialog is caused by a library that we include. If we could identity the library they we could remove it.

We know it can be caused by `NetGroup` and `NetStream`. We have deleted every instance of these from our code base. Is there any other libraries that cause it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, but, in my case, the issue was caused by the mobile version of Monster Debugger (www.demonsterdebugger.com) being included. Removing the mobile version (and linking to the standard version) removed the dialog.

Obviously this will not be the case for everyone else who encounters a similar problem, but I hope knowing the answer to my problem it will assist others.